# Регулярное выражение для валидации имени пользователя

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как должно выглядеть регулярное выражение для проверки имени пользователя, которое не должно начинаться с цифры и должно состоять только из букв, цифр и символа "-".

Вот что я пытался сделать:

```
/[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*$/
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот это выражение: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]+$`. Объяснение:

1. Тут `^` обозначает начало строки
2. `$` - конец строки
3. Далее в `[]` идет перечисление тех символов, что должны быть в начале, так как стоят после `^`
4. `a-zA-Z` - это всего символы английского алфавита во всех регистрах
5. После этого идут остальные символы в `[a-zA-Z0-9-]`.
6. В конце ставится `+` так как необходимо иметь от одного символа, чтобы ник был как минимум 2 символа. Если это не надо, то замените `+` на `*`

Если все правильно понял в вашем вопросе, то решение должно сработать. Советую пользоваться веб-сервисом [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), где есть подсказки и автоматическая валидация результата

Answer (score 0):

У вас  все нормально. За исключением `[^0-9]`. Лучше заменить на `[a-z]` и поставить маркер начала строки `^`, получится так:

```
 '/^[a-z][a-z0-9-]*$/i'
```

Знак `^` означает начало строки.
Знак `$` означает конец строки.
Имея в одной регулярке и `^` и `$` строка пройдёт тест если будет соответствовать регулярке полностью от начала до конца.

Знак `i` в конце - это флаг регистровой независимости. То есть `a` будет означать как `a` так и `A`.